# Rails has_many :through relationship on Address for Origins and Destinations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, has-many-through

I have an Address model that I need to abstract into Origin and Destination.

```rb
class Address
  # ?
end

class Origin
  has_many :destinations
  has_many :addresses, through: :destinations
end

class Destination
  has_many :origins
  has_many :addresses, through: :origins
end
```

Comment: Can you add some more info on how you are using the data? What are the table columns in each?  From the names it feels like it should be turned around, i.e. Address is the join table so an Origin would have many Destinations through Address? But again, just guessing since you don't really define the data model for us.

Comment: I want to have something like addresses_origins_destinations, as a join table. Not sure if the addresses_ is called for...

Comment: Well you won't get much help if you keep your question this vague. If you edit your question to include the table schemas and what your intent is, I could help. What is a typical use case? That will determine what you need and thus your data relationships.